# Why $T: L^1_{\text{loc}}(G) \to C_0^\infty(G)^*$ is an injection?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, lp-spaces, distribution-theory

I am working from *Hilbert Space Methods for Partial Differential Equations* by Showalter. Page 29 states, "Theorem 1.A shows that $T: L^1_{\text{loc}}(G) \to C_0^\infty(G)^*$ is an injection." Page 28 gives the cited theorem

> **Theorem 1.A** $C_0^\infty(G)$ is dense in $L^p(G)$.

What I know: (1) The inclusion $i: C_0^\infty(G) \to L^p(G)$ induces dual map $i': L^p(G)' \to C^\infty_0(G)^*$. (2) $\text{Range}(i)$ dense in $L^p(G)$ implies that $i'$ is an injection. (3) For all $1 \leq p \leq \infty$, we have $L^p(G) \leq L^1_{\text{loc}}(G)$.

But I don't quite see how these facts fit together to give me the transformation $T: L^1_{\text{loc}}(G) \to C_0^\infty(G)^*$. Can $L^1_{\text{loc}}(G)$ perhaps be identified with a subspace of $L^p(G)'$?

**Edit (in response to a comment)** 
The author also writes,

> $f \in L^1_{\text{loc}}(G)$ is assigned the distribution $T_f \in C_0^\infty(G)^*$ defined by $T_f(\varphi) = \int_G f \overline{\varphi}$ for $\varphi \in C_0^\infty(G)$.

Somehow, it didn't click for me that this mapping $f \mapsto T_f$ is the mapping $T: L^1_{\text{loc}}(G) \to C_0^\infty(G)^*$. But still my question remains: What has density of $C_0^\infty(G)$ in $L^p(G)$ got to do with injectivity of $T$?

Comment: What is $T$?...

Comment: Hmm. I had assumed that the reader was supposed to piece together the meaning of $T$ from the clues left by the author. But now that you mention it, in the preceding sentence he defines $T_f(\phi) = \int_G f \overline{\phi}$ for for $f \in L^1_{\text{loc}}$ and $\phi \in C_0^\infty(G)$. Maybe $T$ is the transformation that takes $f \mapsto T_f$?

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather a long comment that a precise proof of the Lemmas and Theorems involve. For sake of simplicity only real valued functions are considered.

In that textbook, the author uses $\mathcal{C}^\infty_0(G)$ for the space of smooth functions on $G$ that have compact support (some other books use $C^\infty_{00}(G)$ or $\mathcal{D}_G$. This is to clarify the meaning of things in your posting.

The Lemma quoted in valid for $0<p<\infty$ as an $F$-space for $0<p<1$ or as Banach space for $1\leq p<\infty)$. When $p=\infty$ the result holds but with $L_\infty$ is equipped with the weak topology $\sigma(L_\infty,L_1)$.

$\mathcal{D}_G$ however is typically equipped with a linear vector topology through an inductive limit of norms
$$p_{m,K}(\phi):=\sup\{|\phi^{(\alpha)}(x)|:x\in K, 0\leq|\alpha|\leq m\}, \operatorname{supp}(\phi)\subset K$$
where $K\subset G$ is compact. (It is possible to write $G=\bigcup_nK_n$ with $\operatorname{int}(K_n)\subset K_{n+1}$. Let $\tau$ be that *somewhat complicated* topology.

Is in this  context that the dual $\mathcal{D}'_G$  of $(\mathcal{C}^\infty_{00}(G),\tau)$ is defined.

The space of distributions $\mathcal{D}'_G$ contains many interstice functionals; amongst them them Radon measures (and this $L^{loc}_1(G)$.

To check that indeed that the inclusion map form $L^{loc}_1(G)$ into $\mathcal{D}'_G$ is injective, suppose
$f,g\in L^{loc}_1(G)$ is such that
$$\int_G f\phi=\int_G g\phi,\qquad \phi\in \mathcal{D}_G$$
Let $K\subset G$ a compact with nonempty interior and consider $\mathcal{D}_K$ (smooth functions with support in $K$).
Appealing to the Lemma when $p=\infty$ (the domain being $K$ and the topology being the weak $\sigma(L_\infty,L_1)$ topology) or the Riesz representation theorem yields
$$\int_K f\phi=\int_K g\phi,\qquad  \phi\in L_\infty(K)$$
this by the Riesz representation theorem $f=g $ almost surely on any relatively compact subset $K$ of $G$, and thus on $G$.

Answer (score 0):

We can view the map as map between $L^1_{Loc}$ to ${C^{\infty}_0}^*$ as $\phi \rightarrow \int f \bar{\phi}$ as mentioned in the question with $f \in L^1_{Loc}$. By choosing $\phi = \phi_{\epsilon}$ where $\phi_{\epsilon}$ is a mollifier we have:

$$\int f(x) \bar{\phi_{\epsilon}}(u - x) = \int g(x) \bar{\phi_{\epsilon}}(u-x)$$

$$\int f(x) \bar{\phi_{\epsilon}}(u-x) = \int g(x) \bar{\phi_{\epsilon}}(u-x)$$

$$\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\int f(x) \bar{\phi_{\epsilon}}(u-x) = \lim_{\epsilon  \rightarrow 0} \int g(x) \bar{\phi_{\epsilon}}(u-x)$$

$$\implies f = g$$ as $L^1_{Loc}$.

or other option is to use $\phi_{r,\epsilon} = \frac{1}{|B(y,r)|} 1_{B(y,r)} * \phi_{\epsilon}$ and appeal Lebesgue differentiation theorem.

Hence $$\int f \phi_{r,\epsilon} = \int g \phi_{r,\epsilon}$$

$$ \lim_{r \rightarrow 0} \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int f \phi_{r,\epsilon} = \lim_{r \rightarrow 0} \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int g \phi_{r,\epsilon}$$

Hence $f(y) = g(y)$ a.e.